# rJava not loading in RStudio, but working in R

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java, rstudio

I managed to install rJava by running `R CMD javareconf -e | tee javareconf.out`

```
cat javareconf.out 
Java interpreter : /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java
Java version     : 1.8.0_201
Java home path   : /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
Java compiler    : /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javac
Java headers gen.: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javah
Java archive tool: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/jar

trying to compile and link a JNI program 
detected JNI cpp flags    : -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include/linux
detected JNI linker flags : -L/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include/linux     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-1SEA_D/r-base-3.5.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o conftest.so conftest.o -L/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR

The following Java variables have been exported:
JAVA_HOME JAVA JAVAC JAVAH JAR JAVA_LIBS JAVA_CPPFLAGS JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH
Running: /bin/bash
```

I installed the rJava package from within R as well (`install.packages("rJava")`). And now, I can use rJava from R, but not from RStudio.

I tried changing the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include Java lib and then installing rJava from within RStudio but to no success. `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"`

What's interesting is that if I open RStudio with `sudo rstudio kill-all` it works as in R, but if I open RStudio via clicking on an icon in my dock I get the following error:

```
> library(rJava)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/home/kzkedzierska/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried reinstalling RStudio (`sudo apt purge rstudio` and manually deleting .rstudio directories left in my home directory) but this did not help...

Any idea what I can do to fix this?

EDIT:

now I see that the issue is that R CMD javareconf did not change the paths for RStudio, from the rJava install log from withing RStudio:

```
checking Java support in R... present:
interpreter : '/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java'
archiver    : '/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/jar'
compiler    : '/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/javac'
header prep.: ''
cpp flags   : '-I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux'
java libs   : '-L/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/lib/server -ljvm'
checking whether Java run-time works... ./configure: line 3766: /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java: No such file or directory
no
configure: error: Java interpreter '/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java' does not work
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rJava’
* removing ‘/home/kzkedzierska/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/rJava’
```

any idea how to change those? Equivalent of running `R CMD javareconf -e` but in Rstudio?

[RStudio alongside R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSqiz.png)